# How can I format minutes into hour and minutes but only show hour if it's > 60 minutes?

Tags: javascript

I have this function that converts minutes into an hour / minute format:

```
return Math.floor(diffMins / 60) + " Hour " + diffMins % 60 + " Minutes.";
```

What I would like to do is to make it so that if there are no hours then the "0 hours" does not show. Can anyone recommend a good way that I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floor; check if more than 0 hours; if not, output empty string; otherwise check if one hour, if yes, output "1 hour", if not, output number of hours + "hours"

```
var h = Math.floor(diffMins / 60);
var hours = (h > 0 ? (h==1 ? "1 hour" : h+" hours") : "");

var mins = diffMins % 60;
return hours + mins > 1 ? mins + " minutes." : " 1 minute." ;
```

Comment: Do you want to add the check for less than 2 minutes to make the word into minute :-)

Answer (score 1):

This would work..

```
return (diffMins>60?Math.floor(diffMins / 60) + " Hour ":"") + diffMins % 60 + " Minutes."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function makePlural(count, words) {
    if (count == 0 || count > 1)
        return count + " " + words[1];

    return count + " " + words[0];
}    

function minutesToString(diffMins) {
    var hours   = Math.floor(diffMins / 60);
    var minutes = diffMins % 60;

    var hoursStr = (hours == 0) ? "" : (makePlural(hours, ["Hour", "Hours"]) + " ");
    var minutesStr = makePlural(minutes, ["minute", "minutes"]);

    return hoursStr + minutesStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return Math.floor(diffMins / 60) ==0 ? diffMins % 60 + " Minutes." : Math.floor(diffMins / 60) + " Hour " + diffMins % 60 + " Minutes."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourFunction(diffMins) {
    if (minutes < 60) {
        return minutes + " Minutes.";
    }
    return Math.floor(minutes / 60) + " Hour " + minutes % 60 + " Minutes.";
}
```